# JS switch statements

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to create is to have a Dropdown-list which allows a user to choose from and whatever is chosen should be written into a cell in the table. I have written the following code but it seems to be not working:

```js
var firstPlay = document.getElementById("all_options").value;

function myFunction() {

  switch (firstPlay) {

    case "Option1":
      document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Option1Text1";
      break;

    case "Option2":
      document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "Option2Tex2";
      break;

    case "Option3":
      document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "Option3Text3";
      break;

    case "Option4":
      document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "Option4Text4";
      break;
  }

}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Select one from:<br>
  <select id="all_options">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
    <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
  </select>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add to the  table below</button>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">empty</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="2">empty</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="3">empty</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="4">empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It seems as only if I choose any option from Dropdown-list the Option1Text1 is going always to be written in the table in the first cell. Is there something wrong with my SWITCH statement that I am using in my code?

Comment: You have initialise your firstPlay value at the beginning of the code 
```
var firstPlay = document.getElementById("all_options").value;
```

Just move this line inside the `myFunction` function. It will work.

Comment: Big thanks Tarun Jain!! That little change did the miracle :) thx again, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix and refactor like this without using switch

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Select one from:<br>
<select id="all_options">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
    <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add to the  table below</button>
<hr>

<script>

let pushedItems = [];

async function myFunction() {
if(pushedItems.length == 4) return
let firstPlay = document.getElementById("all_options").value;
pushedItems.push(firstPlay);
document.getElementById(pushedItems.length).innerHTML = firstPlay; 
}

</script>
<table >
<tr>
<td id="1">empty</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td id="2">empty</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="3">empty</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td id="4">empty</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution! It is working as desired :) Greets!

Comment: Could you please choose it as accepted answer if It solved your problem? You are welcome:) @longus200

Comment: No problem Evren. But …how do I do it? I am a total newbie to stackoverlfow :(